# how to connect HTC phone in Ubuntu for development and app testing?

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-11.04

I am working on phone gap and trying to build an app for Android. When i connect a device HTC Desire HD it connects in a few seconds and when try to run phonegap App on it , it get installed. But, i have another phone Incredible S, whe i try the same procedure on it it shows ?????? tried several things available on net to get it detected and work with ubuntu but unable to do so ? it also says unknown device here is link for the snapshot http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/tfprcxip/Selection_001.png . How to get out of this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to restart your ADB**. Follow the below steps.

1)Open a terminal and login as root.

2)navigate to the directory where you have this ADB. (Normally /opt/android-sdk/platform-tools).

3)now execute ./adb kill-server and then ./adb start-server.

4) Now you should be able to see some msg like this, "Daemon started successsfully".Else repeat 3rd step. That's it.

Comment: I mean u shud navigate to the directory were you have your android-sdk.

Comment: Ahhh Was having the same issue, was getting annoyed. Glad it really is just this simple1